# "It's not...but rather is..." |Vs| "It's not...but rather it's..." |Vs| "It's not...but..."—Is there a rule or is it just about writing style?

Tags: grammar, writing

Here's a random example I just came with to exemplify this. It's not perfect but gets the point across I guess:

1- It’s not a special mental condition or a rare disorder, **but rather is the** consequence of his lifestyle and actions.

2- It’s not a special mental condition or a rare disorder, **but rather it's the**  consequence of his lifestyle and actions.

3- It’s not a special mental condition or a rare disorder, **but the** consequence of his lifestyle and actions.

Comment: I get that the question is about whether to repeat "is", "it's", or neither, but there's also the matter of "rather". "Not A ... rather B" suggests someone declined A and chose B. That's not what's needed here. You could say "It's not A. On the contrary, it's B."

Answer (score 1):

The third statement says it clearly and succintly. The first two may be common in spoken English and acceptable, although the repetition of "is" is redundant.

Comment: Is there any case in which either the 1st or 2nd would be preferable?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. If getting one's thoughts across is the only purpose of communication, all three do it. The second may be more emphatic if spoken with particular stress on "but it is the the consequence of".